# python code can be deployed in AWS lambda but not in localstack

Tags: python-3.x, localstack

I developed a python (v3.6) project that is deployed and actually works within a serverless lambda in my **AWS production plateforme**. This project uses the following dependencies:

```
- awscli==1.16.10
- boto3==1.9.0
- botocore==1.12.0
- psycopg2==2.7.5
- SQLAlchemy==1.2.11
- SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.33.3
- jsonschema==2.6.0
```

Now I want to use localstack to deploy this project within a lambda that I would be able to invoke in order to test my invocation code (not the code of my project that actually works !)

To deploy the project, first I install the dependencies and create a zip file :

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade -t ./
chmod -R 755 .
zip -r lambda.zip .
```

Then, I use the command (with a running localstack) :

```
aws lambda --region eu-east-1 --endpoint localhost:4574 \
    create-function --function-name mylambda \
    --zip-file fileb://lambda.zip
```

However, it returns an error from localstack :

```
....
localstack_1  |     from functools32 import lru_cache
localstack_1  | ImportError: No module named functools32
....
localstack_1  |     raise Exception('Unable to get handler function from lambda code.', e)
localstack_1  | Exception: ('Unable to get handler function from lambda code.', ImportError('No module named functools32',))
```

The module functools32 is used by jsonschema and it is only available for python 2.7 or <=3.2. I am using python 3.6 so I can't install it. Futhermore, I did not have this error when I deploy the same lambda.zip in my AWS production plateforme.

I have realy no idea how to solve this. If someone has an idea to check, I will be very thankful.

Regards,

Answer (score 5):

The way you have done it is very similar to me, aside from when creating the lambda function I append some more flags that define the handler function, runtime etc..., so I would say your error lies there. That being said, I can successfully run lambda on AWS and on Localstack, so this is how I accomplish it:

1. First make a Dockerfile that will install the requirements

   ```
   # Dockerfile
   FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.7
   ENV REQPATH /root/requirements.txt
   COPY ./requirements.txt /root/requirements.txt
   pip3 install -i https://pypi.douban.com/simple -r ${REQPATH} --target=/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
   RUN cd /opt && zip -r /root/lambda-layer.zip *
   ```
2. Now, build the image and get the `.zip` file out of the container:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   docker build -t lambda-layer:my_version ${NOCACHE} .
   id=$(docker create lambda-layer:my_version)
   docker cp $id:/root/lambda-layer.zip ~/lambda-layer.zip
   docker rm -v $id
   ```
3. Now at this point, that `.zip` file can be the one that will need to be uploaded to AWS, as I write the lambda functions directly on their website, but for Localstack, we need to make a new `.zip` file, which contains the same contents as the one just made, but add in a python script for lambda.
4. Write a lambda script, that depends on some third party module, in this case; `requests`:

   ```
   # lambda.py
   import requests

   def handler(event, context):
       print("--- testing localstack lambda ---")
       print("event: ", event)
       print("context: ", context.__dict__)
       r = requests.get("http://192.168.xx.xx/path/")
       print("r: ", r)
       return {"foo": "bar"}
   ```
5. Make a new `.zip` file with the above python script:

   ```
   # shell
   $ cp lambda-layer.zip lambda-layer-localstack.zip
   $ zip -ur lambda-layer-localstack.zip lambda.py

   # Check contents on zip file contain the python 
   # dependencies and lambda function script
   $ unzip -l lambda-layer-localstack.zip
   Archive:  lambda-layer-localstack.zip
     Length      Date    Time    Name
   ---------  ---------- -----   ----
           0  2019-02-02 15:37   python/
         261  2019-02-02 15:43   lambda.py
   ---------                     -------
         261                     2 files
   ```
6. Now we just need to create that lambda function on Localstack

   ```
   $ awslocal --endpoint-url=http://192.168.xx.xx:4569 \
            lambda create-function \
            --function-name=function1 \
            --runtime=python3.7 \
            --role=r1 \
            --handler=lambda.handler
            --zip-file fileb://lambda-layer-localstack.zip
   ```
7. And finally, test that it works

   ```
   $ awslocal --endpoint-url=http://192.168.2.75:4569 \
            lambda invoke
            --function-name function1 result1.log
   {
       "StatusCode": 200
   }

   # On docker-compose logs (docker-compose logs -f)
   localstack_1  | --- testing localstack lambda ---
   localstack_1  | ('event: ', None)
   localstack_1  | ('context: ', {..})
   localstack_1  | ('r: ', <Response [200]>)
   ```

Comment: Very useful and working example, thanks!